# Python: Iterating through worksheets to export to csv

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm doing a summary compare of two workbooks and outputting a third.  I'm doing this by exporting each workbook (identically structured, containing 15 worksheets) to a series of csv files and then doing a table-to-table compare by reading in csv file A and its correspondingly named csv file B converted from the second workbook.

I am using `xlrd` and `csv`

Here's the part of the code that is failing:

```
outpath_a = os.path.join(working_directory, "out_a")  # dir set earlier
workbook_a_sheets = workbook_a.sheet_names()
workbook_b_sheets = workbook_b.sheet_names()

for a in workbook_a_sheets:
    out_csv = os.path.join(outpath_a, a)
    with open(out_csv, 'wb') as oca:
        cw = csv.writer(oca, dialect=csv.excel, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for rownum in xrange(a.nrows):
            cw.writerow(a.row_values(rownum))
```

It is giving me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'nrows'
```

I tried using `unicodecsv` instead of `csv` (`import unicodecsv as csv`), but the error is the same.

Comment: you probably mean `xrange(workbook_a.nrows)`. `a` is the _name_ of your worksheet, not the worksheet itself.

Comment: Wouldn't that search the entire workbook? I want to iterate over each sheet and export each sheet to its own csv file.

Comment: you're right! you have to get the sheet object using its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the sheet name like if it was the sheet object.

You need to call the `sheet_by_name` method on your workbook to get it

fixed loop:

```
for a in workbook_a_sheets:
    out_csv = os.path.join(outpath_a, a)
    with open(out_csv, 'wb') as oca:
        cw = csv.writer(oca, dialect=csv.excel, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        # get sheet object from its name
        a_sheet = workbook_a.sheet_by_name(a)
        for rownum in xrange(a_sheet.nrows):
            cw.writerow(a_sheet.row_values(rownum))
```

Comment: Great!  A small part of the xlrd universe just opened up to me.  This worked, but even better, I understand why now.

Comment: that's the point of attempting something when posting a question (even if it fails)